# How to configure build.gradle files of an existing project with actionbarsherlock lib?

Tags: actionbarsherlock, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I have an existing project MyProject in eclipse that use the library actionbarsherlock (version 4.3.1). The project compiles and runs in android studio, but I don't get build variants. Please help!

**Here is setting.gradle and build.gradle of my root folder (project_workspace):**

```groovy
// setting.gradle:
include ':MyProject'
include ':actionbarsherlock'

build.grade:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
```

**build.gradle of myProject:**

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':C::Users:<myname>:project_workspace:actionbarsherlock')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }

}
```

**build.gradle of actionbarsherlock:**

```groovy
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

I also read a lot of question and answers here, and I looked at the gradle samples, but I don't get it.
Please help me, I never worked with maven or ant before!
If you need more information -> tell me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have working project with libs like this:

**Root folder**:

*settings.gradle*:

```
include ':JazzyListView', ':ABS', ':Volley',':WallCP'
```

*build.gradle*: empty

**ABS folder**:

*build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
}
```

**Main project's folder:**

*build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':JazzyListView')
    compile project(':ABS')
    compile project(':Volley')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 5
        versionName "3.0"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had a lot more work than just editing my build-files. In this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234561/build-gradle-and-project-libs/17271295#17271295 I write what helped me.