# Import library project to Android Studio how to steps

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

currently I'm trying to implement and apply a pull to refresh list view for my sample app. Now I found out about chrisbanes pull to refresh [here](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). Yes I know it's no longer maintaned but I can't find any alternatives. Anyway I tried to read a lot of questions about importing a project and I think I'm always lost about it especially with the gradle structure.

What I tried so far is to import the project in eclipse then gradle export and copy paste it on a directory named libraries following the steps in this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android-using-android-studio/3.0/). I get an error saying *Cannot create class-file*.

As for the other test I've done I always get a gradle error. I forgot the exact error message but most of it are because of gradle.build.

Now can anyone tell me on the steps on how I can import this project library for my Android Studio project on a step by step basis? My apologies for asking too much.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio/16588104#16588104

Comment: @Raghunandan already tried those steps. But it didn't work. first I got tried to import module, the project were built but force closes after run and got some can't locate the custom ListView errors. second step I tried that one and got a gradle error. tried another method and got another error and last I got the cannot create class-file error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234561/build-gradle-and-project-libs. If this doesn't help please post your build.gradle file of your project.