# Android Studio - add library - Failed to notify project evaluation listener

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, addition

I know some topics already exist about that issue but I didn't find a solution.

So i'm trying to add a library to my project and when I `Make Project` the following error message appears: `Failed to notify project evaluation listener`.
My project's structure is as following:

```
MyApp
-libs
--color-picker
---src
---build.gradle
---settings.gradle
-build.gradle
-settings.gradle
```

Here's the app's settings.gradle:

```
include ':app'
include ':libs:color-picker'
```

And the lib's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
dependencies {
    compile project(':libs:color-picker')
 }

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
 }

/**
  * Global version names.
  */
ext {
    propBuildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'
    propCompileSdkVersion = 22
    propMinSdkVersion = 7
    propTargetSdkVersion = propCompileSdkVersion
    propVersionCode = 2
    propVersionName = '2.0'
}
```

Help!!

Comment: Have you tried this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/17265271/712000

Comment: I did but when I add the project's name to the path as following "compile project(':MyApp:libs:color-picker')" the error appearing changes into "Configuration with name 'default' not found

Comment: Please add your solution.

Comment: I'm still having the same issue and I've tried all the other solutions.  What could I be missing?  This should be straightforward... if I need a library, I declare it as a compile dependency and source it from mavenCentral... done?  Nope, errors.