# Android - Getting error when i run project in android studio

Tags: android, build.gradle

I get error while run project 
here is error

```
Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :citruslibrary:generateDebugSources, :citruslibrary:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :library:generateDebugSources, :library:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :payUMoneysdk:generateDebugSources, :payUMoneysdk:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :viewPagerLib:generateDebugSources, :viewPagerLib:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-google_apis-google-19' in inconsistent location '/opt/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19-1' (Expected '/opt/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google-19')
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Cannot evaluate module payUMoneysdk : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
```

I am not able to understand, please help.

Comment: Have you tried, build->clean?

Comment: yes, but not working

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

       // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

Comment: see the edit options under your post, and post the build.gradle(module:app) and save edits

Comment: @UrjaPawar - here is build.gradle(module:app) - https://www.dropbox.com/s/ljm33czjb26u7z8/build_gradle.txt?dl=0, pls check

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17234561/build-gradle-and-project-libs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple, Go to you project - app--->payUMoneysdk--->
.gitignore, open it and remove text written inside